# Inner product on a vector space in a real-valued interval

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a vector space $V = C([a,b])$ where $ a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and and $V$ contains all real-valued continuous functions, then I know that $
\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^b f(t)g(t) dt$ is an inner product given that both f and g are in V. But my question is would $\langle f,g\rangle_2 = \int_a^c f(t)g(t) dt$ be and inner product given that $c \leq b$.

For example, if $V = C([0,1])$, then I know that $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t) dt$ is an inner product of $V$. But would $\langle f,g\rangle_2 = \int_0^{1/2} f(t)g(t) dt$ be an inner product on $V$? My instinct is telling me that it is an inner product, but not on $V$ (I don't know if that even makes sense) but I don't know how to justify my answer.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Take a function $f$ that is zero on $[0,\frac{1}{2}$], but not the zero function on $[0,1]$. Then $\langle f,f\rangle_2=0$, even though $f\neq 0$, which shows that $\langle-,-\rangle_2$ is not positive definite, hence not an inner product. You are right that if you tweaked the vector space (to a different interval),, then this would be an inner product on *that* vector space.

Comment: think about $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto 0$ for $x \le \frac 1 2 $ and $x \mapsto 2x - 1$ else. Then what is $\langle f,f \rangle$ and what should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't be, because $$\int_0^{1/2}f^2=0,$$ won't implies that $f=0$ on $[0,1]$. However, it will be a semi-inner product.

Answer (score 0):

Take an example $$f(t)=\begin{cases} 
      0&, & x\leq 1/2 \\
      x-1/2&, & x\gt 1/2 
   \end{cases}$$
Clearly in this case $~\langle f,f\rangle_2 = \int_0^{1/2} \{f(t)\}^2 dt=0~,$ but this does not implies that $~f(t)=0~$ on $[0,1]$.
Hence $~\langle f,g\rangle_2$ is not an inner product on $V = C([0,1])$ as positive definiteness property does not hold.